# How to pull out all number sequences from string with Oracle regular expression?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to write SQL query which pull out all number sequences from given string. For example from string like:

```
 '<rej:idnymu s7fn we2dfgdg="http://dfgrgdfgfZszik">278579133</rej:>
 <rej:idnymu k3op d5dfgdg="http://dfgrgdfgfZszik">118545112</rej:>
 <rej:idnymu s1rd s9dfgdg="http://dfgrgdfgfZszik">271238461</rej:>'
```

I want to extract something like:

```
278579133, 118545112, 271238461
```

The most important thing and the most hard to do is to ignore cases when single number occurs like:  "s7fn" or "we2d".

So far i was able to do query like this:

```
SELECT Regexp_replace( 
'<rej:idnymu s7fn we2dfgdg="http://dfgrgdfgfZszik">278579133</rej:>          <rej:idnymu k3op d5dfgdg="http://dfgrgdfgfZszik">118545112</rej:>          <rej:idnymu s1rd s9dfgdg="http://dfgrgdfgfZszik">271238461</rej:>' 
, '([^0-9])', '') RESULT 
FROM   dual;
```

But do not have any idea how to separeta number sequences and more important how to get rid of single numbers what i mentioned earlier.

Could someone suggest how to achieve this?

UPDATE

Whole string looks more or less like this:

```
'<efwewfsdf/>
<asdf>
<qwe>
<rej:aaa ns2=rnsjvnsvjrlntjnbsnbltdbk">64-0203-0875/4</rej:aaa>
<rej:bbb ns2=bmtbrbpnrtusrnbdbd k">06396</rej:bbb>
<rej:ccc ns2=vmkfbkmbkfmgkmfgkbgfk">4567650</rej:ccc>
<rej:ddd ns2=zxczxczczxczxczxk">402341198</rej:ddd>
<rej:eee ns2=asdasdasdazxck">723112</rej:eee>
<rej:eee ns2=adasdasdawawqweqwek">342253</rej:eee>
<rej:eee ns2=bgbgfnnhnhnhnhnhnk">656345</rej:eee>
<rej:fff ns2=ewretyrtyghnk">352</rej:fff>
<rej:ggg ns2="vzxczdvdbdfgs">asd.Gdsa</rej:ggg>
<rej:hhh ns2="zcsasdqwfwgerbyn">W1_22</rej:hhh>
</qwe>
</asdf>'
```

normally it is much longer and i am obtaining it from blob. Query looks like this:

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_SUBSTR(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 300)) || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 2300)), '<rej:aaa[^<]*')), '.*>', '') aaa, 
REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_SUBSTR(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 300)) || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 2300)), '<rej:bbb[^<]*')), '.*>', '') bbb,
REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_SUBSTR(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 300)) || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 2300)), '<rej:ccc[^<]*')), '.*>', '') ccc,
REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_SUBSTR(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 300)) || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 2300)), '<rej:ddd[^<]*')), '.*>', '') ddd,
REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_SUBSTR(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 300)) || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 2300)), '<rej:eee[^<]*')), '.*>', '') eee,
REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_SUBSTR(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 300)) || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 2300)), '<rej:eee[^<]*')), '.*>', '') eee,
REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_SUBSTR(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 300)) || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 2300)), '<rej:eee[^<]*')), '.*>', '') eee,
REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_SUBSTR(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 300)) || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 2300)), '<rej:fff[^<]*')), '.*>', '') fff,
REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_SUBSTR(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 300)) || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(tn.blob_value, 2000, 2300)), '<rej:ggg[^<]*')), '.*>', '') ggg,
tn.blob_value
FROM table_name tn
```

The problem is that 3 of "rej:eee" tags are identical and i do not know how to distinguish them. Also strings has 1-5 "rej:eee" tags so it is not fixed number.

Hope it is more transparent now and sorry for my bad english.

Thanks
Rav

Comment: I don't really get the "single number" constraint. Could you show inputs that should match and inputs that should not match?

Comment: Inputs that match(sequence of numbers):
45637832, 13548283, 23428582
Inputs that not match:(single number):
2, 6, 3, 1, 7, 4
In the given string numbers that not match are always glued with letters: "s7fn we2dfgdg", "k3op d5dfgdg", "s1rd s9dfgdg"

Comment: Can the dash `-` sign be outside of the value you are interested in?

Comment: probably you should parse the xml, instead of using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with t(d) as (
  select '<efwewfsdf/>
<asdf>
<qwe>
<rej:aaa ns2=rnsjvnsvjrlntjnbsnbltdbk">64-0203-0875/4</rej:aaa>
<rej:bbb ns2=bmtbrbpnrtusrnbdbd k">06396</rej:bbb>
<rej:ccc ns2=vmkfbkmbkfmgkmfgkbgfk">4567650</rej:ccc>
<rej:ddd ns2=zxczxczczxczxczxk">402341198</rej:ddd>
<rej:eee ns2=asdasdasdazxck">723112</rej:eee>
<rej:eee ns2=adasdasdawawqweqwek">342253</rej:eee>
<rej:eee ns2=bgbgfnnhnhnhnhnhnk">656345</rej:eee>
<rej:fff ns2=ewretyrtyghnk">352</rej:fff>
<rej:ggg ns2="vzxczdvdbdfgs">asd.Gdsa</rej:ggg>
<rej:hhh ns2="zcsasdqwfwgerbyn">W1_22</rej:hhh>
</qwe>
</asdf>' from dual 
), t1(d) as (
select SUBSTR(d, REGEXP_INSTR(d, '<[A-Za-z]{3}:', 1, level), REGEXP_INSTR(d, '</rej:[A-Za-z]{3}>', 1, level) - REGEXP_INSTR(d, '<[A-Za-z]{3}:', 1, level))
  from t
connect by rownum < LENGTH(d) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(d, ':[A-Za-z]{3}>', ''))
)
select REGEXP_REPLACE(d, '^<rej:.*">', '') ff from t1

FF
--------------
64-0203-0875/4
06396
4567650
402341198
723112
342253
656345
352
asd.Gdsa
W1_22
```

Comment: Does the string contain multiple `<rej>` tags and are any needed numbers outside these tags? If the answer to either is yes, this solution will need tweaking...

Comment: The problem is that i cannot split string like you did in your solution. Is there any way to do it without splitting?

Comment: Show me more input data and I will provide you another solution

Comment: @user2871219 take a look at my answer now.