# Get part of message from LOB content

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, xml-column

I have some XML content(less than 2000 bytes) in a LOB (Large OBject) column. I have used `dbms_lob_substr(messagebody)` to get the actual XML content but I need to get the exact value of a particular node.

eg.

```
<first name>xyz</first name>
<last name>abcd</last name>
```

I need the value of say `<first name>`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Its all XMl nodes..<first name> XYZ </first name>..How can i get a value of particular node say <firstname>

Comment: See my previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25400877/3686755)

Comment: Great way to do it..but marking the other as correct as he responded first. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML seems to be missing a root node? If your XML data is as you show it, you can get XMLTable() function to parse it if you put it in a dummy root node, for example like this:

```
select x.firstname
  from mytable,
  xmltable(
   '/rootnode'
   passing xmltype('<rootnode>'||myclobcol||'</rootnode>')
   columns
      firstname varchar2(100) path 'firstname'
  ) x
```

If you need to get multiple values at the same time, you just add to the columns clause:

```
select x.*
  from mytable,
  xmltable(
   '/rootnode'
   passing xmltype('<rootnode>'||myclobcol||'</rootnode>')
   columns
      firstname varchar2(100) path 'firstname',
      lastname  varchar2(100) path 'lastname',
      middleini varchar2(10)  path 'middleinitial'
  ) x
```